# SSL enabled Microservice architecture with Spring boot

Tags: apache, spring-boot, ssl, microservices

**My Setup**

I have built my project using multiple spring boot applications as micro services. And there is another spring boot application called as api-gateway, which acts as a reverse-proxy for all other micro services. I am using ZuulProxy for this. Each micro service comes up with it's own tomcat with different ports and api-gateway routes the traffic across these. And micro services talk to each other over http.

I am spinning up the micro services and api-gatway as docker containers. This is my back-end setup.

I have a web client developed in html, angularjs and this is also running as docker container. This web application calls back-end APIs over http REST. This container is an apache container exposing 80 port.

So, when someone hits **http://example.com** it reaches web app container and loads the UI. This UI uses **http://api-example.com/*** for it's REST calls. So, in apache container(httpd.conf) I have added VirtualHosts like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot "<path to my UI files>"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName api-example.com
  ProxyPass / http://apigateway:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://apigateway:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

[Overview of my setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IkGF.png)

**Question**

Everything is working as expected over http. But what is the right way to enable SSL for this setup.

**What I tried**

I bought a certificate and configure in web app container and UI is loading fine in the browser over https. Since, I was using **http://api-example.com/*** in UI for api calls, browser thrown me error saying non secure call in secure application. So, I have changed the api url to https in UI code. For that I have added a VirtualHost in httpd.conf like this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName api-example.com
  ProxyPass / http://apigateway:8081/ timeout=600
  ProxyPassReverse / http://apigateway:8081/ timeout=600
</VirtualHost>
```

This whole thing is deployed in a server. And I am able to access application over https from my browser.
But, it is not working from other's laptop. It is working sometimes and it is failing rest of the time, with a CORS error while UI accessing **https://api-example.com/**.

**Complete error in the browser console :** 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-example.com/api/auth/login?' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

By the way, I also have below code to comply with CORS, in my api-gateway

```
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        config.addExposedHeader("X-AuthToken");  //This is must for browser to read X-AuthToken header
        config.addExposedHeader("X-filename");  //This is must for browser to read X-filename header
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

This looks very strange, because I am not getting this error in my browser. My colleagues have tried all other browsers and cleared the browser cache also.

So, I am suspecting the way I have done this architecture. Can someone please tell me what mistake I made or suggest a better way to setup something like this.

NOTE: I wanted to have all my services and web app in the same machine for now.

Comment: Can you midify as below and see if it works? I suspect source.registerCorsConfiguration("/*", config); has problem.
config.setAllowCredentials(true);
config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
config.addAllowedHeader("*");
config.addAllowedMethod("*");
source.registerCorsConfiguration("*", config);

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify as below and see if it works? I suspect `source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);` creating problem.

```
config.setAllowCredentials(true);
config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
config.addAllowedHeader("*");
config.addAllowedMethod("*");
source.registerCorsConfiguration("*", config);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Alok Singh, but unfortunately this did not work.